# Questions about the use of concept and requires

Tags: c++, c++20

Does anyone know why this code below returns 0? When will it return 1?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
concept A = requires(T t){{t} -> std::same_as<bool>;};
int main()
{
    std::cout << A<bool> << "\n";
}
```

I run it on Compiler explorer with gcc13.1 (compiler options: -std=c++20) and it did return 0.

Comment: @JesperJuhl if you spend too much time around compilers, you start thinking like a compiler, and forget that English is not intended to be parsed rigorously like source code.  :)

Comment: I wonder if this was inspired this weeks [C++ quiz](https://hachyderm.io/@shafik/110374104504750216)

Answer (score 5):

In your case, the compound requirement `{t} -> same_as<bool>` means that the type of `decltype((t))` must satisfy `same_as<bool>`.

Since `t` in `decltype((t))` is parenthesized, it will be treated as an ordinary lvalue expression, which makes it have type `bool&` instead of `bool` so the constraint is not satisfied.

You can constrain the return type to be `same_as<bool&>` or use the C++23 *decay-copy* (`auto(x)`) to remove the *cvref*-qualifier of the expression

```
template<typename T>
concept A = requires(T t) {
  { auto(t) } -> std::same_as<bool>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a pretty surprising result. A similar problem to this came up [recently in a clang frontend bug report](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/62328) and which inspired my recent [C++ weekly quiz](https://hachyderm.io/@shafik/110374104504750216).

The result is a consequence of the wording in [[expr.prim.req.compound]p1.3.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req#compound-1.3.2.sentence-1) which says (*emphasis mine*):

> The immediately-declared constraint ([temp.param]) of the type-constraint **for decltype((E))** shall be satisfied.

and has the following examples right below:

> [Example 1: Given concepts C and D,
>
> ```
> requires {   
>  { E1 } -> C;   
>  { E2 } -> D<A1, ⋯, An>;
> };
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> requires {  
>  E1; requires C<decltype((E1))>;  
>  E2; requires D<decltype((E2)), A1, ⋯, An>;
> };
> ```
>
> (including in the case where n is zero). — end example]

Note the parenthesized expression in `decltype` in the examples  e.g. `decltype((E1))`.

The consequence of the parenthesized expression in `decltype`, is that the resulting type is `bool &` and not `bool` as you were expecting. This is due to wording in [[dcl.type.decltype]p1.5](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1.5):

> otherwise, if E is an lvalue, decltype(E) is T&, where T is the type of E;

which says that the result of a parenthesized *id-expression* of type *T* will be *T&* if the expression is an *lvalue* which it is in this case.

If on the other hand we had:

```
template <typename T>
concept B=requires(T t){{!t}->std::same_as<bool>;};
```

note the `!t` which would give us a *prvalue* then the result would be `bool` due to [[dcl.type.decltype]p1.6](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1.6):

> otherwise, decltype(E) is the type of E.